# buttons in div rendered differently because of text content

Tags: html, css

I have four 100px*100px sized buttons in a div. However they are positioned different depending on their text content.

This is the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Memo demo</title>
  <style>
    button {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="buttonHolder">
    <button type="button" >X</button>
    <button type="button" ></button>
    <button type="button" >X</button>
    <button type="button" >X</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it is rendered in Chrome:
[image: chrome screenshot]

This is how it is rendered on Firefox:
[image: firefox screenshot]

What should I do to make them appear aligned?

Comment: set the vertical-align property for the button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default buttons are aligned along their last line of text (the "baseline", same as `inline-block` elements). If there is no text, the bottom border is used instead, which happens in your snippet. To change that, you can use `vertical-align`, either `top`, `bottom` or `middle` , whatever fits best for your particular situation:

```css
button {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Memo demo</title>
  <style>
    button {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="buttonHolder">
    <button type="button">X</button>
    <button type="button"></button>
    <button type="button">X</button>
    <button type="button">X</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would consider using `baseline` somewhere because it's the main issue as it's the default alignment

Answer (score 1):

You can add `&nbsp;` for a small blank space.

**OR**

You can use `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonHolder">
  <button type="button" >X</button>
  <button type="button" >&nbsp;</button>
  <button type="button" >X</button>
  <button type="button" >X</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try to had a [float property](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/float) in order to align buttons.

Here is an example with `float: left;`

```css
button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonHolder">
  <button type="button" >X</button>
  <button type="button" ></button>
  <button type="button" >X</button>
  <button type="button" >X</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `display: flex` on the `#buttonHolder`. It works for me in Firefox and Chrome.

```css
#buttonHolder {
  display: flex
}
button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonHolder">
  <button type="button" >X</button>
  <button type="button" ></button>
  <button type="button" >X</button>
  <button type="button" >X</button>
</div>
```